# Stubbing out methods that explicitly implement an interface using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, explicit-interface

How can I stub out methods that explicitly implement an interface using Rhino Mocks?

As I understand it, Rhino Mocks requires stubbed out methods to be virtual, and explicitly implemented interface members are not virtual.

Comment: Is this in relation to a PartialMock?  If not, if you just have an interface dependency, you can create a stub for the interface and then stub out the methods and return values for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently.  In fact, the feature of intercepting explicitly implemented interface members just got fixed yesterday in the Dynamic Proxy code (Rhino Mocks uses Dynamic Proxy under-the-covers to intercept method calls):

http://support.castleproject.org/projects/DYNPROXY/issues/view/DYNPROXY-ISSUE-107